# How interrupt bash script inside Docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker, interrupt

I'm running bash script inside docker with such command

```
docker exec -it c_id bash -c  "./cmd.sh"
```

where cmd.sh is of form like

```
op1
op2
...
op19
op20
```

Sometimes I need just to interrupt this shell script totally. But Ctrl+Z not working and if I use Ctrl+C it will interrupupt current operation in bash and will go to the next

So how to make this?

***NOTE:***

I can't launch docker in totally interactive mode like

```
docker exec -it c_id bash
```

because it will become unstable. But in such interactive mode Ctrl+Z works fine which could successfully interrupt bash script at once

Comment: Remove`-it`. Do you need terminal and interactive when executing `-c` script?

Comment: Yes,  I need to see output and interrupt bash which executes

Comment: It has nothing to do with that.... Do you need to _input_ data and have the script have it's own terminal?

Comment: `docker stop` will kill a container's main process along with anything you've done in secondary debugging shells.  As you've described the setup, should you update your image to have `CMD ./cmd.sh` so you don't need the debugging shell?

Comment: looks like 'docker stop' is solution, but not very convinient since I need to restart service then again

Answer (score 0):

You can send it a SIGSTOP to pause it, then a SIGCONT to restart it.

So you would exec a new `bash` in the container running your original process. Then you will need the `procps` package to get the PID:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install procps
```

Then, find the PID of the process you want to pause, using `ps` and pause it with:

```
kill -s STOP <PID>
```

and continue with:

```
kill -s CONT <PID>
```

Of course, you could more simply use `pkill` instead of `kill` if you know the name of the process you want to pause.

Comment: Bit strange answer, the question was how to interrupt shell script while running ( NOT stop/start process ). So I meant just kill this shell script inside docker. Also your suggestion  looks a bt non-convinient. Looks like docker stop is more easy option than go inside container and killing processes

Comment: Maybe just a language thing. The Cambridge Dictionary defines *"interrupt"* as *"to cause an activity to stop briefly"* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interrupt which is how I interpreted the question. I'll leave it standing in case it's helpful for anyone else. You also referred to `Ctrl-Z` which is normally for pausing rather than `Ctrl-C` for aborting which reinforced my belief that you wanted to pause and continue.

Comment: Okay, it seems that I was not clear. My apologies. Maybe now you could suggest modified answer to original question? I understand that 'docker stop' is solution but it's also not very convinient.

Comment: You can just send SIGTERM or SIGABORT if you want to terminate the process rather than pause it.

Comment: Yes, but it's even more inconvinient than 'Docker stop'.

Comment: What's inconvenient about `docker exec -it c_id 'pkill cmd.sh' You can make an alias or a bash function if it's something you do often. And if you don't do it often, it surely won't matter that it takes 5 seconds to type.

Comment: hmm, I though that it's impossible to kill like 'pkill cmd.sh', I though the pid is needed for this, not just shell script name